# How do I limit the items in a "List Box" column based on another column's input in a table in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I tried setting up a relationship although I don't know if this is how I'm meant to do it:
[image: I tried setting up a relationship although I don't know if this is how I'm meant to do it.]

Category column settings:
[image: Category column settings]

Description column settings:
[image: Description column settings]

Linked to the table that contains different type of furniture, "Furniture":
[image: Linked to the table that contains different type of furniture, "Furniture"]

Furniture design:
[image: Furniture design]

### **So what I want to do, is make it so that when you choose a furniture category, you can only choose from furniture descriptions of that category:**

[image: So what I want to do, is make it so that when you choose a furniture category, you can only choose from furniture descriptions of that category... But at the moment, it shows all the descriptions:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this can be done using only tables — you'll have to create a form that will limit the selection in the descriptions listbox based on the category.

Also, there are a number of problems with your data structure:

- I imagine multiple `Furniture`s can have the same `CATEGORY`. This means that `CATEGORY` cannot be the primary key -- a uniquely identifying piece of data -- for `Furniture`. I would suggest adding a **Long** number column called `FurnitureID`. If you make this an **Autonumber** column, every new record will get a new number by default; otherwise you'll have to insert the number by hand.
- Once you have such a column, you should have a corresponding column — AKA the foreign key column — in `Stock` of the same type (or **Long** if the `FurnitureID` is an **Autonumber**). These two columns should be related in the Relationships window. The relationship means that every<sup>1</sup> `Stock` record must have a related `Furniture` record with the same data in both records.
- Once you've done that, there is no need to repeat the `CATEGORY` and `DESCRIPTION` fields between the `Stock` and `Furniture` tables. This means no duplicate data, and no potential conflicts.

<sup>1. Depending on how the column is defined, it might be possible to have no data in the foreign key column in the `Stock` record; but this is relatively uncommon</sup>